# Print a pattern like AAA to ZZZ starts like AAA AAB AAC.... AAZ ABA ABB ... ZZZ?

Tags: java

i have tried the below code but it shows some error..

```
        String str="AAA";
        char[] ch=str.toCharArray();
        int length=str.length();
        for(int i=length-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
             for(int j=65;j<=90;j++)
             {
                 System.out.println(str.replace(ch[i] ,(char)j));
             }
        }
```

Comment: Please include the specific error you get.

Comment: It runs fine. It just doesn't produce the output you want.

Comment: This is more a of a logic problem than a coding problem.  I would increment each character in a 3 nested loop personally

Comment: `for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)` works just fine in Java. There's rarely a need to be messing around with character codes.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to generalise [Permutation of an array, with repetition, in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157656/permutation-of-an-array-with-repetition-in-java) to solve your problem, although that might be overkill if it's just for 3 characters. To see why yours doesn't work, grab a pen and paper and write down what happens at every iteration of the array (and read what `String.replace` does, because it's not what you think).

Comment: The solution I sumbitted works regardless of string length it computes +1 with carrying, but it was downvoted twice without comments.

Comment: I removed my answer because 1) the question is not clear, 2) downvoters didn't explain, 3) the OP didn't accept answers. And it was the only correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is three loops (one for each character place):

```
for(char c1 = 'A'; c1 <= 'Z'; c1++){
  for(char c2 = 'A'; c2 <= 'Z'; c2++){
    for(char c3 = 'A'; c3 <= 'Z'; c3++){
      System.out.println("" + c1 + c2 + c3);
    }
  } 
}
```

At the end I am adding to a String, or else you will get a numerical value, instead of String like you are expecting:

```
System.out.println('A' + 'B' + 'C');  // Output: 198
System.out.println("" + 'A' + 'B' + 'C');  // Output: ABC
```

Comment: But the OP didn't explain what he wanted, as he uses length-1 one can guess that the number of letters may be greater than 3.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood.  I thought OP wanted to produce the example they posted in the title.

Comment: If I was going to generalize it I would probably make it recursive.

Answer (score 0):

`String.replace()` method is replacing all occurrences of oldChar in string with newChar value.

You can try to use `lastIndexOf()` to archive your goal.

Answer (score 0):

I am incrementing each character in each loop. This code gives correct output:-

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
String s = "AAA";
StringBuilder ss = new StringBuilder(s);
char ccc = ss.charAt(0);
for(int i = 0 ; i < 26 ;i++)
{


    ss = ss.replace(0,1,Character.toString(ccc++));

    char cc = ss.charAt(1);
    for(int j = 0 ; j < 26;j++)
    {

        ss = ss.replace(1,2,Character.toString(cc++));
        char c = ss.charAt(2); 
        for(int k = 0 ; k < 26;k++)
        {

            ss = ss.replace(2, 3,Character.toString(c++));

            System.out.println(ss);
        }
        ss.replace(2, 3, "A");
    }
    ss.replace(1, 2, "A");
    }
```

Hope this helps