# Java program for permutation and combination

Tags: java

I was given a program with the below inputs

```
List of integers = {1,2,3}
int n = 5;
```

The output should be the unique combination of the list elements which can be added to form the integer n.

The expected output = 5 
because the unique combinations which can form 5 using the above array is

```
1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,2
1,1,3
2,2,1
2,3
```

The function I have created is like below

```
static void printAllCobinations(List<Integer> rooms,int t){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<rooms.size();i++){
        int temp = t;
        while (temp>0){
            if((rooms.contains(temp))){
                count++;
            }
            temp-=rooms.get(i);
        }
    }
```

Its giving the output as 6, as in addition to the above scenario its considering 
3,2 also.

Actual expectation is if 2, 3 is considered no need to consider 3,2 .

How can i accomplish that ?

Note : the input array and n can change.

Comment: The current output of your function is 321312 if you print it out and that results in a count of 6. I think you need to rethink your function completely

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permutation of an array, with repetition, in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157656/permutation-of-an-array-with-repetition-in-java)

Comment: Though this problem can be solved with the help of permutations with repetition, comparing the sum of items of every result with the target one, but this approach is good only if `n` is very small, because of the complexity of this algorithm, which is, if I am not mistaken, O(n!). So for n=5 the value of n! is 120, and n=12 will take about 479001600 iterations.  So even if pc is very powerful, it will take too long to wait for the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arr = new int[s.length() / 2 + 1];
```

*if s.length is 3 the arr.length = 3*

*if s.length is 4 the arr.length = 3*

I have the feeling your problem lies there.

As an advice, I would suggest sepparating the part of the code that translates input from the code that actually calculates stuff. And then test them separately to see if you get the outcomes you want.

Comment: sorry the program will take a string with space separated digits that part was for converting it to the list. update the question with the correct code

Answer (score 0):

Your task looks like the coin exchange problem, which is described [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/). 
But instead of simply getting the amount of possible permutations you want to enumerate the results, so code needs to be changed.

For example my solution may look like the following in Java 8:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Solution {
    private List<Integer> rooms;
    private int numberToCheck;
    private Map<Integer, Set<List<Integer>>> cache;

    public Solution(List<Integer> rooms, int numberToCheck) {
        this.numberToCheck = numberToCheck;
        this.cache = new HashMap<>();
        this.rooms = rooms;
    }

    public Set<List<Integer>> solve() {
        return count(numberToCheck);
    }

    private Set<List<Integer>> count(int currentNumber) {
        if (currentNumber <= 0) {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }

        if (cache.containsKey(currentNumber)) {
            return cache.get(currentNumber);
        }

        Set<List<Integer>> currentSolutions = new HashSet<>();
        cache.put(currentNumber, currentSolutions);
        for (Integer room : rooms) {
            if (currentNumber == room) {
                currentSolutions.add(Collections.singletonList(room));
            }

            Set<List<Integer>> previousSolutions = count(currentNumber - room);
            for (List<Integer> previousSolution : previousSolutions) {
                List<Integer> solution = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
                    addAll(previousSolution);
                    add(room);
                }};
                Collections.sort(solution);
                currentSolutions.add(solution);
            }
        }
        return currentSolutions;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> rooms = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
            add(1);
            add(2);
            add(3);
        }};

        int n = 5;

        Solution solution = new Solution(rooms, n);
        Set<List<Integer>> results = solution.solve();
        System.out.println("Total results: " + results.size());

        System.out.println("Simple results: " + results);
        List<List<Integer>> sortedResults = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>() {{
            addAll(results);
        }};

        sortedResults.sort((list1, list2) -> -Integer.compare(list1.size(), list2.size()));
        System.out.println("Sorted results: " + sortedResults);

        System.out.println("Line by line:");
        sortedResults.forEach(list -> {
            List<String> stringList = list.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println(String.join(",", stringList));
        });
    }
}
```

The output will be like:

```
Total results: 5
Simple results: [[1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 2]]
Sorted results: [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 3], [2, 3]]
Line by line:
1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,2
1,2,2
1,1,3
2,3
```

This approach uses Dynamic programming technique (or memoization) to store intermediate results to avoid unneeded recomputation. Method `count` is computed only once for the unique number, and rooms are also enumerated only once at that time. So, assuming, that the number of rooms is k, the computation is called n*k times. And if we needed only to count possible results, the algorithm complexity would be O(k*n). So to compute the count of results for the given task it will require 3*5=15 iterations. Which is very fast.

But it is needed to enumerate all possible solutions, the number of which may combinatorically (according to the input) increase complexity in terms of consuming time and space, and there are some sort operations which add extra overhead, which can take to n! operations in worst case.

This approach is running very fast on my PC for n=200 with the same list of rooms {1,2,3}, and it takes several seconds to show the result.